# Make redis cache expire at certain time everyday

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I am using node-redis. I have a cron job that updates my db and I have redis cache that caches the db response.

The problem I'm having is that my cron job runs everyday at 12am, however I can only set redis cache to expire in x seconds from now. Is there a way to make node-redis cache expire everyday at 12am exactly. Thanks.

Code:

```
const saveResult = await SET_CACHE_ASYNC('cacheData', response, 'EX', 15);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can use https://redis.io/commands/expireat command, if you use https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis package as redis driver, code will be like this

```
const redis = require('redis')
const client = redis.createClient();
const when = (Date.now()+24*60*60*1000) / 1000;
client.expireat('cacheData', when, function(error){....};


``
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I had the same problem with an application. My work around was creating a new timespan based on the time difference between my set and expiration time. Here is my code:

```
private TimeSpan GetTimeSpanUntilNextDay(int hour)
        => new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(1).Ticks).AddHours(hour) - DateTime.Now;
```

Using the stack exchange lib for a 6 AM absolute expirition time the code looks like so:

```
public async Task<bool> SetEntranceAsync(string key, MYTYPE unserializedObject)
{
    var db = _multiplexer.GetDatabase();
    var jsonValue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unserializedObject);

    return await db.StringSetAsync(key, jsonValue, GetTimeSpanUntilNextDay(6));
}
```

I used C# but you should be able to do the trick in any language.

Comment: I ended up doing exactly this with javascript where I'd get the current time and calculate how much time was left until the 23 hour mark in seconds.